# Select/4 on a list of lists

Tags: prolog

On prolog i'm trying to solve the following exercise for connect 4

```
?- generate_move(2,[[1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 0, 1]],BP).
BP = [[1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]] ;
BP = [[1, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]] ;
BP = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]] ;
BP = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]] ;
BP = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]] ;
BP = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]] ;
```

Where the rule is that is returns every possible move left for a player provided (in this case 2)

I was thinking of using select/4 to find every result possible for each list in the list of lists, then join it. But i'm failing to "condense" results and my second iteration of findall fails:

```
generate_move(_,[],[]).
generate_move(Player,[H|T],[FinalLine|FinalBoard]) :-
    findall(X0,(select(0, H, Player, X0)),FinalLine),
    join_results(FinalLine,T,FinalBoard),
    generate_move(Player,T,FinalBoard).

join_results([],[],[]).
join_results([H|T],LeftOvers,FinalBoard) :-
    append([H],LeftOvers,FinalBoard),
    join_results(T,LeftOvers,FinalBoard).
```

Any tips? My join_results returns false at the second call and so does my findall.

Comment: What do you mean by 'every possible move'? If you drop tokens in from the top, why do you need to look at the other rows, the possible moves are "zeros in the top row", aren't they?